# Automatically run a logon process from IE

Tags: windows, scripting, internet-explorer

I need to write a script which will post username and password onto a server url, fetch the session cookie and save it into IE's cookie directory. Basically I want a script to automatically log me into a site simply by running it.

Any help on how to do it? Anything from C, VBS to python, perl will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[LibGmail](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libgmail/files/)** is an opensource python library used to login to gmail account from an external  program.. it just simulates (hacks) the gmail login approach using scripting.

> I need to write a script which will
>   post username and password onto a
>   server url, fetch the session cookie
>   and save it into IE's cookie directory

take a look at the code, this surely got the implementation you are looking for. You can easily tweak into this to meet your needs.

Comment: I don't think it saves the session cookies into Internet Explorer's cookie directory.